# WCF How to change the prefix in a request

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, soapui

In my WCF project, I have a function "Add New Policy" that takes two parameters. In the request of this function, the prefix used for those two parameters is "cch". How I can change the prefix of those two parameters to "tem".

This is the request:

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" 
xmlns:cch="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CCHVisitorsInsuranceWS.NS.NewPo
    licy">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <tem:AddNewPolicy>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <tem:PolicyEntity>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <cch:PolicyNumber>?</cch:PolicyNumber>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <cch:eNumber>?</cch:eNumber>
             </tem:PolicyEntity>
          </tem:AddNewPolicy>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>

<xs:element name="AddNewPolicy"> 
  <xs:complexType> 
    <xs:sequence> 
      <xs:element xmlns:q3="schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/…; minOccurs="0" name="PolicyEntity" nillable="true" type="q3:PolicyEntity"/>        
    </xs:sequence> 
   </xs:complexType> 
</xs:element>


    <wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"; 
    xmlns:wsap="schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy‌​"; 
    xmlns:wsa10="w3.org/2005/08/addressing"; xmlns:tns="tempuri.org/"; 
    xmlns:msc="schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract"; 
    xmlns:soapenc="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"; 
    xmlns:wsx="schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex"; 
    xmlns:soap="schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"; 
    xmlns:wsam="w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata"; 
    xmlns:wsa="schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing";
    xmlns:wsp="schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy";
    xmlns:wsaw="w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl"; 
    xmlns:soap12="schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"; 
    xmlns:wsu="docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/…";   
    xmlns:xsd="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"; 
    name="CCHVI" 
    targetNamespace="tempuri.org/">...</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: Why do you want to change?

Comment: Because the requested form is like this :                                                        
                <tem:PolicyNumber>?</tem:PolicyNumber>
                <tem:eNumber>?</tem:eNumber>

Comment: Can you show the service interface definitions?

Comment: And the WSDL, please?

Comment: Is this what you need:

Comment: <xs:element name="AddNewPolicy">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element xmlns:q3="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CCHVisitorsInsuranceWS.TEM" minOccurs="0" name="PolicyEntity" nillable="true" type="q3:PolicyEntity"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

Comment: <wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"

Comment: xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="CCHVI" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">...</wsdl:definitions>

Comment: In future could you please add extra information to the original question rather than in comments?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that your ***elements*** `AddNewPolicy` and `PolicyEntity` have not been defined in any namespace; this is why they have been assigned to the default Microsoft WCF namespace of `http://tempuri.org/`.

You need to define them as part of the same namespace as the `PolicyEntity` ***type***, i.e. your `http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CCHVisitorsInsuranceWS.NS.NewPolicy`
namespace.

Personally, whenever I see `http://tempuri.org/`in a generated WSDL or XSD it says to me that I've got something wrong with my namespaces. Once I've got rid of it completely it's probably OK.